# Live Site Demo on Django

Tags: django, django-cms

I have been looking for some documentation on how to create a site demo similar to what django cms and mezzanine have. All I really need is a way to show possible clients what the site can do when logged in as an admin and allow them to change things without causing harm. Is there an open source project that I can refer to or anything like that? I appreciate the help!

Comment: Are you asking to where someone has already made a demo or are you asking how to make one yourself?

Comment: Well I have no problem with making one myself I just need a starting point. If there is a django app already set up then great though.

Comment: One approach might be to have a separate demo login view that loads a `json` fixture each time someone logs in -- so all the data is wiped/reset on each access.

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be to use the `loaddata` management command to re-load a `json` fixture for the particular demo account's data.

---

*(Not tested)*

```
# forms.py
class DemoLoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']
        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'initial': '', 'size': '80'})
        }

# views.py
from django.core.management import call_command
class DemoLoginView(FormView):
    template_name = 'demo-login.html'
    form_class = DemoLoginForm
    success_url = '/admin/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        login(self.request, authenticate(username=form.instance.username, password=new_password))

        call_command("loaddata", "/path/to/demo_account_fixture.json", verbosity=0)

        return super(DemoLoginView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: How do you set a timer for the demo just like Django cms Divio 15 minutes demo? So the demo ends after 15 minutes.